# How to remove TEXT of checkout/Order Review page in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, layout, magento-enterprise, grand-total

how to add custom text in layout page in magento ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this by translation feature of Magento.

- Go to **`app/locale/<locale_folder>/Mage_Checkout.csv`** and write your translation like:

> "text to translate", "translation of text"

- Flush Magento cache and check frontend.

You can also do the same from **`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/locale/<locale_name>/translate.csv`** file.

**Note:** For translation to work correctly, text to be translated should be enclosed within **$this->__('text to be translated')** in phtml file.

Comment: Its Working Excellent ,Thank you so much @MohitKumar

Answer (score 1):

Go to following file:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout/shipping.phtml

OR

app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/tax/checkout/shipping.phtml
```

Change following line:

```
<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getTotal()->getTitle()) ?>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getShippingExcludeTax()) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This code should be

```
<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <?php echo $this->__('Shipping') ?>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getShippingExcludeTax()) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```